# How to setup Xcode project to use SwiftUI and AppKit

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, appkit

I have an app that I would like to use SwiftUI however I would like for my app to also run on older version of macOS that does not support SwiftUI. I would like to know how I can setup my initial file so that it setup like a swiftui project for macOS 11 and above and while running on a version of macOS that does not support SwiftUI it will use the tradition AppKit method.

I am new to Xcode and swift development and would like to know if I am setting my entry file up correctly

```
//
//  DemoSwiftUIApp.swift
//  DemoSwiftUI
//
//  Created by Jerry Seigle on 6/16/23.
//

import SwiftUI
import Cocoa

@main
@available(macOS 11.0, *)
struct DemoSwiftUIApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
        var contentView: ContentView! // Replace "ContentView" with the name of your SwiftUI view



    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create a SwiftUI view
        let contentView = ContentView() // Replace "ContentView" with the name of your SwiftUI view
        
        // Create a window with a content size based on the SwiftUI view's size
        let window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300), // Set initial width and height as per your requirements
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        // Set the SwiftUI view as the content view of the window
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView.frame(width: 480, height: 300)) // Set width and height as per your requirements
        
        // Set the window's minimum size to the content view's size
        window.contentMinSize = NSSize(width: 480, height: 300) // Set minimum width and height as per your requirements
        
        // Set the window's initial size to the content view's size
        window.setContentSize(NSSize(width: 480, height: 300)) // Set initial width and height as per your requirements
        
        // Center the window on the screen
        window.center()
        
        // Show the window
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }


    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```

Comment: You can't use the SwiftUI lifecycle entry point (your `DemoSwiftUIApp`) if the OS doesn't support SwiftUI. You could, however, use a Storyboard entry point.

Comment: Do you really need to run your app on Mac that does not support SwiftUI ? SwiftUI is supported since Catalina which is supported by Mac from 2012.

Comment: I am new to swift and swiftui. I need the app to run on macOS 10.15 & newer because I still have many users using 10.15, lol. The issue is that my computer is running Xcode 14 and opening a new swiftui project you can't set the target to 10.15 without errors. with @main, scene, windowgroup. I am not sure how to setup the project to run on 10.15 with Xcode 14. Could someone help with that or give me better understanding